# How to include forward slash "/" in pytest -k command line option

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to use the pytest -k option to filter out specific tests.  The filter does not work and returns an error when it contains a forward slash "/".  I tried backslash escaping it with one and two backslashes but still the same error.  Any idea how to do this?

```
ERROR: Wrong expression passed to '-k': 
test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_US_PLEAFS_L0_ipv4.yml: 
at column 22: unexpected character "/"
```

```
$ pytest tools/test_pinger.py --testinfo topoA_PEs.yml --params_file topoA_r28_params.yml --ulog -s --collect-only -k "test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_US_PLEAFS_L0_ipv4.yml"
=============================================================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/as2863/pythonProjects/p1-automation, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: csv-2.0.1, check-0.3.5, pylama-7.6.6, dependency-0.4.0, instafail-0.4.0, ordering-0.6, allure-pytest-2.8.20, repeat-0.7.0, reportportal-5.0.3
collected 18 items

<Package tools>
  <Module test_pinger.py>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtracer_topoA_L0.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtracer_topoA_L10.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtracer_topoA_ADI_L0.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtracer_topoA_ADI_L10.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtracer_topoA_AVPN_L0.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtracer_topoA_AVPN_L10.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtracer_topoA_MOW_L0.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtracer_topoA_MOW_L10.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[new/pingtracer_topoA_US_PEs_L0.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_MOW_PLEAFS_L0_ipv4.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_MOW_PLEAFS_L0_ipv6.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_PEs_L0_ipv4.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_PEs_L0_ipv6.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_PEs_L10_ipv4.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_US_PLEAFS_L0_ipv4.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_US_PLEAFS_L0_ipv6.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger_mpls[pingtracer_topoA_ADI_L10.yml]>
    <Function test_pinger_mpls[pingtracer_topoA_AVPN_L10.yml]>

=========================================================================================================================== 18 tests collected in 0.34s ===========================================================================================================================
ERROR: Wrong expression passed to '-k': test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_US_PLEAFS_L0_ipv4.yml: at column 22: unexpected character "/"

(p1_netmiko_3-3-3) asilver@ubuntuP1-SYSlog-S1:~/pythonProjects/p1-automation$
```

Comment: Same error whether I include the closing square bracket or not.  Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-k` is (somewhat intentionally) inflexible -- it is not meant to allow all inputs for matching.

that said, there are two ways to do what you want:

1. adjust your `-k` expression slightly:  `pytest -k 'test_pinger and ping_topoA_ADI_US_PLEAFS_L0_ipv4'`
2. use the test id directly **(this appears to be what you're attempting anyway)**: `pytest 'tools/test_pinger.py::test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_US_PLEAFS_L0_ipv4.yml]'`

---

disclaimer: I'm a pytest core dev

Comment: Thx for the clarification on the behavior of -k. I'm actually using Jenkins as a GUI front end to run different pytests.  The user has the option to select multiple tests from a pull down dialog.  I use the -k option and combine each test the user selects (with "or").  I'll have to come up with an alternative way to do this...

Comment: I can also specify multiple test_ids directly on the command line... Do you know how many I can add on the command line?  10, 20,? more?  Thx
`pytest tools/test_pinger.py::test_pinger[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_PEs_L10_ipv4.yml] tools/test_pinger.py::test_pinger_mpls[pingtrace/ADI/ping_topoA_ADI_PEs_L10_ipv4.yml] --testinfo topoA_PEs.yml --params_file topoA_r28_params.yml --ulog -s  --collect-only`

Comment: as many as will fit for your operating system